# url rewriting problem

Tags: php, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

in my `.htaccess` file i have the following

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

so when i wrote `http://mydomain.com/am/home` it will be redirected to `http://mydomain.com?lang=am&id=home`

---

but i have a `cms` folder, and i need to go to

`http://mydomain.com/cms/index.php` when wrote

`http://mydomain.com/cms` but it doesn't happen.

what can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=cms
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [B,L]
```

When you go to `/cms`, Apache probably does a 301 to `/cms/`, therefore your rewrite rule would match. This will avoid matching `/cms/`.

Comment: Great. Thanks much. but in this case $1 in RewriteCond refers to the next RewriteRule only? what about, iif i have many Rewriterules?

Comment: @Syom Yes, only the next. If you need for many, you try putting this one before the others: `RewriteRule cms/ - [L]`. The last (L) stops a round of replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$    $1/index.php  [L]`